# Resize Icon every second using GestureDetector's onLongPressStart

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

This problem is pretty much very similar to messenger's icons. As long as you press that icon, the larger it gets.

This would be fun for others to use soon!

I'm new to flutter but if someone has an idea on how to implement this, I'm very much willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **ScaleTransition** widget that accept **animation** value

```
_controller = AnimationController(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), vsync: this, value: 0.1);

_animation = CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.bounceInOut);

ScaleTransition(
    scale: _animation,
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: child
  )
```

and in your longPress just call

```
_controller.forward();
```